# Issues with using parameters for a K-S test and understand the result

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, kolmogorov-smirnov

I'm trying to run a K-S test on some data. Now I have the code working, but I'm not sure I understaned whats going on, and I also get an error when trying to set the loc. Essentially I get both the KS and P-test value. But I'm not sure I fully grasp it, enough to use the result.

I'm using the scipy.stats.ks_2samp module found [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html).

This is the code I am running

```
from scipy import stats

np.random.seed(12345678)  #fix random seed to get the same result
n1 = len(low_ni_sample)  # size of first sample
n2 = len(high_ni_sample)  # size of second sample

# Scale is standard deviation
scale = 3

rvs1 = stats.norm.rvs(low_ni_sample[:,0], size=n1, scale=scale)
rvs2 = stats.norm.rvs(high_ni_sample[:,0], size=n2, scale=scale)
ksresult = stats.ks_2samp(rvs1, rvs2)
ks_val = ksresult[0]
p_val = ksresult[1]

print('K-S Statistics ' + str(ks_val))
print('P-value ' + str(p_val))
```

Which gives this:

```
K-S Statistics 0.04507948306145837
P-value 0.8362207851676332
```

Now for those examples I've seen, the loc is added in as this:

```
rvs1 = stats.norm.rvs(low_ni_sample[:,0], size=n1, loc=0., scale=scale)
rvs2 = stats.norm.rvs(high_ni_sample[:,0], size=n2, loc=0.5, scale=scale)
```

If I do that however, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-342-aa890a947919>", line 13, in <module>
    rvs1 = stats.norm.rvs(low_ni_sample[:,0], size=n1, loc=0., scale=scale)

  File "/home/kongstad/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/stats/_distn_infrastructure.py", line 937, in rvs
    args, loc, scale, size = self._parse_args_rvs(*args, **kwds)

TypeError: _parse_args_rvs() got multiple values for argument 'loc'
```

Here is a snapshot, showing the content of the two datasets being used.
low_ni_sample, high_ni_sample.
[image]

So my questions are:

1. Why cant I add a loc value and what does it represent?
2. Changing the scale changes the result significantly, why and what to go by?
3. How would I plot this out in such a way it makes sense?

After running Silma's suggestion I stumbled upon a new error.

```
from scipy import stats

np.random.seed(12345678)  #fix random seed to get the same result
n1 = len(low_ni_sample)  # size of first sample
n2 = len(high_ni_sample)  # size of second sample

# Scale is standard deviation
scale = 3

ndist = stats.norm(loc=0., scale=scale)

rvs1 = ndist.rvs(low_ni_sample[:,0],size=n1)
rvs2 = ndist.rvs(high_ni_sample[:,0],size=n2)

#rvs1 = stats.norm.rvs(low_ni_sample[:,2], size=n1, scale=scale)
#rvs2 = stats.norm.rvs(high_ni_sample[:,2], size=n2, scale=scale)
ksresult = stats.ks_2samp(rvs1, rvs2)
ks_val = ksresult[0]
p_val = ksresult[1]

print('K-S Statistics ' + str(ks_val))
print('P-value ' + str(p_val))
```

With this error message

```
    rvs1 = ndist.rvs(low_ni_sample[:,0],size=n1)

TypeError: rvs() got multiple values for argument 'size'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that you should first create an instance of the normal distribution before using it:

```
ndist = stats.norm(loc=0., scale=scale)
```

then do

```
rvs1 = ndist.rvs(size=n1)
```

to generate `n1` samples drawn from a normal distribution centered on 0 and with a standard deviation `scale`.
The location is therefore the mean of your distribution.

Changing the scale changes the variance of your distribution (you get more variability), so this obviously impacts the KS test...

As for the plot, I'm not sure I see what you mean... if you want to plot the histograms, then do

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(rvs1)
plt.show()
```

Or even better, install seaborn and use their [`distplot` methods](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/distplot_options.html), for instance the KDE.

Overall I would advise you to try to read a little more on distributions and KS tests before you go any further, see for instance the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test).

**EDIT**
the code shown above is used to generate random samples from a standard distribution (which I assumed was your goal, to compare with your samples).

If what you want to do is directly compare your two sample data, then all you need is

```
ksresult = stats.ks_2samp(low_ni_sample[:,0], high_ni_sample[:,0])
```

again, this is assuming that `low_ni_sample[:,0]`and `high_ni_sample[:,0]` are 1D-arrays containing many measurements of the quantity of interest, cf. [ks_2samp documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html)

Comment: Thank you @Silmathoron. I will take you up on that advise. Oh and I already use seaborn, lovely module.

Comment: it is indeed ;)

Comment: I'm getting an error on the size now.

ndist = stats.norm(loc=0., scale=scale)

rvs1 = ndist.rvs(low_ni_sample[:,0],size=n1)
rvs2 = ndist.rvs(high_ni_sample[:,0],size=n2)

 

 rvs1 = ndist.rvs(low_ni_sample[:,0],size=n1)

TypeError: rvs() got multiple values for argument 'size'

Comment: You'll need to be more specific... can you add an edit to your question with the new error?

Comment: There is only one argument, remove the low_ni_sample... also always check the function doc in Scipy, it's usually well documented

Comment: But the low_ni_sample is the data of the first, and high_ni_sample is the second. If I dont include that, then all it runs through are the amount of entries in my data and not the actual content of the data

Comment: I finally got it. I can see why I confused you(and myself!) You are absolutely right. It is working as intended now. Sorry about that :)